# Factoring risk premium in to Forward Rate calculation

Tags: risk, fx, forward-rate

This is a self study question. I'm calculating a forward rate.

Specifically, I have that in a country X, the Spot Rate is 5X/1US. I also have that the 1 year interest rate is 13% in country X and inflation is 12%.  The US interest rate is 4% with 3% inflation.

I'm computing the forward rate as:

$F= S(1+i_d)/(1+i_f) = 5 *(1+.04)/(1+.13) = 4.602.$

However I'm also told that X's market risk premium is 300 basis points above US treasuries. I'm unsure how to factor that in....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to factor in the risk premium or the inflation rates to get the Forward Rate.  The calculation you are making is from the idea of [Covered Interest Rate Parity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interest_rate_parity).  To calculate the forward rate all you need are the two interest rates.

I'm not sure if the question is trying to confuse by giving extra data.  Inflation rates and risk premia can be important for related calculations.